# Decode PKCS-7 request

Tags: java, servlets, encryption, request, pkcs#7

I have a servlet and the content type of my request is of type : application-pkcs-7

And how do i decode the request ?

Any ideas ?

I learnt that i can use openssl to decode , but not much docs on that .

Comment: Sorry! My mac went into some deep trouble.And that too I was looking into some other issue. Couldn't check the posts regularly.Now everything is fine.You have given a clear definition owlstead

Comment: No problem Achilles, I hope you still got all your data. I'll delete my previous comments, you may do the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's probably a signature or an encrypted piece of data. It's old name is PKCS-7 (of RSA labs, publicly available standard) but it is also known as CMS (Cryptographic Message Syntax, publicly available RFC). CMS is a container format for different kinds of encryption. You can parse it in Java using the open source Bouncy Castle libraries - "bcmail" in particular, but you probably need some kind of key if it is encrypted. If it is signed, you could simply parse the plain text data from it and ignore the signature, I guess, depends on the application really.

[UPDATE] Since 1.47 the necessary functionality is in the PKIX library of Bouncy Castle.

Comment: Couple lines of code could explain it way much better than many "about" words. No offence, just saying, your answer doesn't answer only points where to dig.

Comment: @Maxim see the test code of the bouncy castle libraries, I don't know what's in the PKCS#7 so it's hard to know which example to choose.

Answer (score 1):

Should work in this way

```
CMSSignedData cmsSignedData = new CMSSignedData(byte[] signedData);
CMSProcessable cmsProcessable = cmsSignedData.getSignedContent();
```

In my case it didn't though, because of unknown tag entry while parsing data

Comment: That's what I said. CMS is a container format. It may contain signed data, or it may contain encrypted data or something else. Put it through `openssl asn1parse` and check the first OID to see what's inside.

Comment: @owlstead yep, you're right, without understanding what is data (enveloped, signed, encrypted, etc.) there is no definite answer.